# Characterization of the continuity of a linear map $u:A \subset E \to F$ defined in a subspace $A$ of an $LF-$space $E$

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, topological-vector-spaces

Let $E$ be an $LF-$space, $\{E_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ a sequence of definition of $E$, $F$ an arbitrary locally convex space.

We know that a linear map $u:E \to F $ is continuous if, and only if, for each $k$ the restriction $u|E_k$ of $u$ to $E_k$ is a continuous linear map of $E_k$ into $F$.

I would like to know if there are any criteria of this type to analyze the continuity of an application $u:A\subset E \to F$ defined in a subspace $A$ of $E$ where $A=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k$, with $A_k \subset E_k \subset E$. For example, $A=C_c^\infty(\Omega)$, $A_j=C_c^\infty(K_j)$, $E_j=C_c^0(K_j)$, $E=C_c^0(\Omega)$, $K_j$ a sequence of compact subsets of $\Omega$ such that $\Omega=\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} K_j$, $K_j \subset \overset{\circ}{K}_{j+1}$ and $u:C_0^\infty(\Omega) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, where $C_0^\infty(\Omega)$ is equipped with the topology induced by $C_c^0(\Omega)$.

More precisely, if the following result holds:

> **Theorem:** Let $E$ be an $LF-$space, $\{E_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ a sequence of definition of $E$, $F$ an arbitrary locally convex space, $A$ a subspace of $E$ with $A=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k$, $A_k \subset E_k \subset E$, and $u$ a linear map of $A$ into $F$. The application $u:A \to F$, where $A$ is equipped with the topology induced by $E$, is continuous if, and only if, $u|_{A_k}:A_k \rightarrow F$ is continuous, where $A_k$ is endowed with the topology induced by $E_k$.

The implication $(\Rightarrow)$ holds, since the topology induced by $E$ in $A_k$ is equal to the topology induced by $E_k$ in $A_k$.

However, I have no idea if the converse of the above statement is valid.

Comment: I strongly expect that the converse doesn't hold, but so far I don't know where to look for a counterexample.

Comment: @DanielFischer Can you tell me if in the example I gave above this statement is valid? This question came up while I was reading Proposition 21.2 in the Trèves book, in which it characterizes Radon measures. However, the author omitted the details of the proof.

Comment: You mean that $u \colon A \to F$ is continuous if the restriction to $A_j$ is continuous for every $j$? That is the case here. Let $u_j$ be the restriction of $u$ to $A_j$. Since $A_j$ is dense in $E_j$, every $u_j$ has a unique continuous extension $v_j$ to $E_j$. Then the $v_j$ combine to a map $v \colon E \to F$, and $u = v\lvert_A$. So $E$ being a strict $LF$-space and having $A_k$ dense in $E_k$ for all $k$ is sufficient for the converse to hold. (It's easily seen to not be necessary.)

Comment: @DanielFischer What is the definition of application $v$?

Comment: $v\lvert_{E_j} = v_j$, or we could also state it as $v = \bigcup_j v_j$. Since $E_j$ is a topological linear subspace of $E_{j+1}$ for all $j$ we have $v_j = v_m\lvert_{E_j}$ for all $m \geqslant j$, so the $v_j$ fit together to give a well-defined map with domain $E$.

Comment: @DanielFischer. Thank you! If you want I can edit the question and you can post your comment as an answer.

Comment: Don't. At least, not yet. I want to think about the question as posed some more.

Comment: And I just noticed that for my argument as written $F$ needs to be complete. If e.g. $F = A$ and $u = \operatorname{id}$, the argument obviously doesn't work (though in that case $u$ is obviously continuous). But if $F$ isn't complete, we consider its completion, let's call it $G$. Then $u_j \colon A_j \to F$ is continuous iff $u_j \colon A_j \to G$ is continuous, thus we get a continuous $v \colon E \to G$ such that $u$ is the restriction of $v$ to $A$, and $u$ is continuous as a map to $F$ iff it is continuous as a map to $G$. Hence we may assume $F$ to be complete anyway.

Comment: @DanielFischer I hadn't noticed, because I was thinking in the above example ($F=\mathbb{C}$). Can you tell me if $C_c^\infty(K)$  is dense in $C_c^0(K)$?

Comment: Yes, it is. For $f \in C_c^0(K)$, given $\varepsilon > 0$ we can find $\delta > 0$ such that $\lvert f(x)\rvert < \varepsilon/2$ if $\operatorname{dist}(x, \Omega\setminus K) < 3\delta$. We can find $\varphi \in C_c^0(K)$ with $0 \leqslant \varphi \leqslant 1$, $\varphi(x) = 1$ if $\operatorname{dist}(x,\Omega\setminus K) \geqslant 2\delta$, $\varphi(x) = 0$ if $\operatorname{dist}(x, \Omega\setminus K) \leqslant \delta$. The convolution of $\varphi\cdot f$ with a suitable mollifier belongs to $C_c^{\infty}(K)$ and differs from $f$ by less than $\varepsilon$.

Comment: @DanielFischer  I took a function $\theta \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, $\theta(x) \geq 0$, $\hbox{supp } \theta \subset B(0,\delta)$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\theta(x)dx=1$ and $\psi(x)=\theta \ast (\phi \cdot f)(x)$. Then, $\hbox{supp } \psi \subset K$, $\psi \in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$, i.e. $\psi \in C_c^\infty(K)$.  However, I couldn't see why $|\psi(x)-f(x)|=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\theta(y)|f(x)-f(x-y)|dy<\varepsilon$.

Comment: It is if $\delta$ is small enough, but how small is small enough depends on $f$. The point is that $f$, having compact support, is _uniformly continuous_. Thus there is an $\eta > 0$ such that $\lvert f(x) - f(y)\rvert < \varepsilon/2$ whenever $\lvert x-y\rvert < \eta$. We can assume $\eta \leqslant \delta$. Then take $\theta$ with $\operatorname{supp} \theta \subset B(0,\eta)$. First note that we have $\lvert f(x) - \varphi(x)f(x)\rvert < \varepsilon/2$ for all $x$. Write $g = \varphi\cdot f$ for brevity. Next, note that for all $x$ we have ...

Comment: $$\lvert g(x) - (\theta \ast g)(x)\rvert = \biggl\lvert \int_{\lVert y\rVert < \eta} \bigl(g(x) - g(x-y)\bigr)\theta(y)\,dy\biggr\rvert \leqslant \int_{\lVert y\rVert <\eta} \lvert g(x) - g(x-y)\rvert\cdot \theta(y)\,dy \\ < \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \int_{\lVert y\rVert < \eta} \theta(y)\,dy = \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$ by the choice of $\eta$ and the assumptions on $\theta$. Then $\lvert f(x) - (\theta \ast g)(x)\rvert \leqslant \lvert f(x) - g(x)\rvert + \lvert g(x) - (\theta\ast g)(x)\rvert$ gives the desired bound.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The converse is not generally valid. Since you didn't require that $A_k = A \cap E_k$ for all $k$ I can give an explicit (but somewhat silly) example.

Let $E = c_0(\mathbb{N})$ the space of all (complex or real) sequences converging to $0$, and $E_k = E$ for all $k$, endowed with the $\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert_{\infty}$-topology. Let $A = c_{00}(\mathbb{N})$ the subspace of all sequences wih only finitely many nonzero terms, and $A_k = \{ x \in A : n > 0 \implies x_n = 0\}$. Then the inductive limit topology on $A$ is strictly finer than the subspace topology induced by $E$. Since the $A_k$ are finite-dimensional, every linear map with domain $A_k$ is continuous, but e.g.
$$x \mapsto \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} n\cdot x_n$$
is not continuous in the subspace topology.

This is, as I said, however a silly example, since it is natural to take $A_k = A \cap E_k$. So far I haven't found an example where the subspace topology on $A$ is strictly coarser than the inductive limit topology on $A$ induced by the $A_k$. However, such examples exist, even for $A$ closed in $E$, according to Remark 13.2 in Trèves book<sup>(1)</sup>:

> Let $E$ be an $LF$-space, $\{E_n\}$ a sequence of definition of $E$, and $M$ a closed linear subspace of $E$. It is not true in general that the topology induced on $M$ by $E$ is the same as the inductive limit topology of the $F$-spaces $E_n \cap M$. One should be careful not to overlook this fact (the author has made the mistake a few times in his life and so also have a few other utilizers of the $LF$-spaces!).

Unfortunately, Trèves didn't give an example of that phenomenon.

However, in the situation you're particularly interested in, the subspace topology on $C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$ induced by $C_c^0(\Omega)$ is indeed the inductive limit topology induced by the $C_c^{\infty}(K_j)$ (viewed as topological subspaces of $C_c^0(K_j)$).

This is generally the case if $A$ is a subspace of $E$ such that $A_k = A \cap E_k$ is dense in $E_k$ for every $k$ (since Trèves requires each $E_k$ to be a topological subspace of $E_{k+1}$; for a more general definition of $LF$-spaces this may not hold).

Consider a linear map $u \colon A \to F$, where $F$ is a Hausdorff locally convex space, such that $u_k = u\lvert_{A_k}$ is continuous for every $k$. Let $G$ be the completion of $F$. View $u$ and the $u_k$ as maps to $G$. Then, since $G$ is complete, $u_k$ is uniformly continuous, and $A_k$ is (by assumption) dense in $E_k$, there is a unique (uniformly) continuous map $v_k \colon E_k \to G$ with $v_k\lvert_{A_k} = u_k$. By general principles, these $v_k$ are linear. The uniqueness of the continuous extension guarantees that $v_k = v_m \lvert_{E_k}$ for all $m \geqslant k$, thus the $v_k$ fit together to define a linear map $v \colon E \to G$, namely $v = \bigcup_k v_k$, or
$$v(x) = v_k(x) \quad\text{if } x \in E_k\,.$$
By the above remark, $v$ is well-defined. Clearly $v\lvert_{E_k} = v_k$, hence $v$ is continuous. And of course we have $u = v\lvert_A$, whence $u$ is continuous in the subspace topology. Immediately, we only get that $u \colon A \to G$ is continuous, but since $F$ is a topological subspace of $G$ and $u(A) \subset F$ it also follows that $u \colon A \to F$ is continuous.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> *Topological Vector Spaces, Distributions and Kernels*, Academic Press, 1967

Answer (score 1):

The converse is not true even if $A_k=A\cap E_k$. This is not an exotic phenomenon but the heart of the matter of applications of LF-spaces.

Let $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be open, $P$ a non-zero polynomial in $d$ varibales, and $P(\partial)$ the corresponding PDO on $\mathscr D'(\Omega)$ which is the transposed of $P(-\partial): E\to E$ for $E=\mathscr D(\Omega)=C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ which is the *mother of all LF-spaces*. The range $A$ of $P(-\partial)$ is closed in $E$ if and only $\Omega$ is $P$-convex for supports if and only if $P(\partial)$ is surjective on the space of $C^\infty$-functions. In this case, the inverse $u$ of $P(-\partial):E\to A$ satisfies that all restrictions  $u|_{A\cap E_k}$ (where $E_k=\mathscr D(K_k)$ for a compact exhaustion of $\Omega)$) are continuous but $u$ is not continuous on $A$ endowed with the subspace topology of $E$ if $P(\partial)$ is not surjective on $\mathscr D'(\Omega)$. A concrete example that this may happen is the wave equation on the complement of a cone in $\mathbb R^3$.

These are results of Hörmander (*On the range of convolution operators*, Ann. Math. (1962)). A good starting point is Floret's *Some aspects of the theory of locally convex inductive limits* (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304020808708090 -- unfortunately behind a paywall). If house advertising is permitted, my Springer Lecture Notes *Derived Functors in Functional Analysis* also contain some information about this question.