# Is the $LF$ topology on $\mathcal{C}_c^k(\Omega)$ necessary?

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, topological-vector-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be open in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $1\leq k < \infty$, and $\{K_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ a sequence of nested compact sets whose union is $\Omega$. Consider the nested Frechet spaces of $k$ times continuously differentiable functions with support in $K_n$, $\mathcal{C}_c^k(K_n)$, each equipped with the topology induced by the seminorms

$$\|f\|_{K}=\sup_{|p|\leq k}(\sup_{x\in K}|(\delta/\delta x)^p f(x)|)$$
where $p$ is a multi-index and $K$ are the compact sets in $K_n$.

Let $\mathcal{C}_c^k(\Omega)$ be the vector space of $k$ times continuously differentiable functions on $\Omega$ with compact support. I am trying to convince myself of the claim (e.g. Treves, *Topological Vector Spaces, Distributions and Kernels*, 1967, p132) that the *LF* topology induced on this space by $\mathcal{C}_c^k(K_n)$ is strictly finer than the topology induced by the space of *all* $k$ times continuously differentiable functions on $\Omega$, $\mathcal{C}^k(\Omega)$, with the topology defined by the family of seminorms

$$\|f\|_{K}=\sup_{|p|\leq k}(\sup_{x\in K}|(\delta/\delta x)^p f(x)|)$$

where $K$ are the compact sets in $\Omega$.

In that spirit, I am trying to think of, say, a linear functional that is continuous on each of $\mathcal{C}_c^k(K_n)$ but not on $\mathcal{C}^k(\Omega)$. [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3769000/characterization-of-the-continuity-of-a-linear-map-ua-subset-e-to-f-defined/3769689#3769689) gives an example where an $LF$ topology is finer than an alternative topology on the space of sequences converging to zero. However, it would be nice to have an example in the $\mathcal{C}_c^k(\Omega)$ setting in order to justify use of the $LF$ topology when dealing with continuously differentiable functions with compact support. Any clues in this direction would be much appreciated.

P.S. Alternatively, it would be really great to have an example of a neighbourhood of zero in $\mathcal{C}_c^k(\Omega)$ with the $LF$ topology which is not to be found in the topology induced by $\mathcal{C}^k(\Omega)$.

Comment: It turns out that, in introducing the LF topology for the above space, Treves presents here a solution in search of a problem. The latter (for example) consists of how to ensure Radon measures are continuous on the space of continuous compactly-supported functions. I guess it sometimes pays to skip ahead!

Comment: Nevertheless, it is not clear to me yet that the topology is *necessary* and that Radon measures could not be shown to be continuous linear functionals in the second (i.e. standard) topology. Therefore, the question remains open.

Comment: Take a sequence $x_n\in \Omega$ tending to the boundary of $\Omega$ (i.e., every compact subset contains only finitely many $x_n$). Then $\phi(f)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(x_n)$ defines a linear functional on $C_c^k(\Omega)$ which is continuous with respect to the LF-space topology (which, btw, is a locally convex inductive limit of Banach spaces and hence even a so-called LB-space) but not with respect to the topology induced by $C^k(\Omega)$.

Comment: Thank you - that's really useful. On the $LB$ point, if we say ${\mathcal{C}_c^k(K_n)}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a strict inductive sequence of *Frechet* spaces, a neighbourhood of zero, $\mathcal{N}$, in the $nth$ member of the sequence is also a neighbourhood of zero in the $n+1th$ member of the sequence. This doesn't seem to me to be true if it is a sequence of *Banach* spaces, since $\sup_{|p|<k}(\sup_{x\in K_n}|(\delta / \delta x)^p f(x)|)$  does not define a neighbourhood of zero in $K_{n+1}$. Thus $\mathcal{N}$ is a member of the $LF$ space but not the $LB$ space. Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. $C^k_c(K)=\{f\in C^k(\Omega): f(x)=0 \text{ for all $x\notin K$}\}$ is a closed subspace of  the Fréchet space $C^k(\Omega)$ which happens to be a Banach space.  If $X$ is a proper subspace of locally convex space $Y$, a $0$-neighbourhood $N$ in $X$ is **never** a $0$-neoghbourhood in $Y$. Maybe you nean that for a topological subspace $X$ of $Y$, the absolutely convex $X$-neighbourhhod $N$ can be written as $X\cap M$ for a $Y$-neighbourhood of $0$.